# Backup my internal hard drive

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage

I changed my CPU and I have all my files in old HDD (500 gb). I taught of using it as a slave drive to my new 1TB HDD. But what if it get formatted.

How can I recover it without losing the data and the problem is I have OS installed in it and I have not formatted C drive.